# Django - Class Based View trouble How Combine DetailView with ListView in same template

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views

can anyone tell me how combine detailview with list view and show info in the same template, i'll explain you, i'm learning Django and i am trying to create a Questions and Answer web app, and i need to show the question with all its awnsers, i need in my detailview for a specific question show below all it awsers, something like stackoverflow does

```
#models.py
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


# Create your models here.
class Question(models.Model):

    # user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="question", null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    cant_resp = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    question_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=QUESTION_TYPES_CHOICES)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description




class Anwser(models.Model):

    # user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="anwser", null=True)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=400)
    date= models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

```
#and this are my views.py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.urls import reverse, reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import  LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views import generic

from .forms import QuestionForm, AnwserForm
from .models import Question

# Create your views here.

class QuestionListView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'anwserquestions/question_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'questions'

    def get_queryset(self):

        return Question.objects.all()

def createquestion(response):
    if response.method == "POST":
        print("Its POST method")
        form = QuestionForm(response.POST)
        # user =response.user
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data["name"]
            description=form.cleaned_data['description'],
            question_type=form.cleaned_data['question_type'],
            # date=form.cleaned_data['date'],
            t = Question(name=name, description=description, question_type=question_type, cant_resp=0)
            t.save()
            response.user.question.add(t)  # adds the to do list to the current logged in user

            # return HttpResponseRedirect("/%i" %t.id)
            return redirect('anwserquestions:question-list')

    else:
        form = QuestionForm()

    return render(response, "anwserquestions/question_create.html", {"form":form})

    
class QuestionDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'anwserquestions/question_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'question'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Question.objects.all()


class QuestionDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.DeleteView):
    template_name = 'anwserquestions/question_delete.html'
    context_object_name = 'question'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('anwserquestions:question-delete')

    # def get_queryset(self):

    #     return Question.objects.all()
```

Comment: I'm assuming the Question and Answer models share some kind of relationship, that's where you need to focus on. But it will also help if you show your `model.py` and `views.py` it will help us see what you've done so far and make appropriate inputs.

Comment: i let you my models and my view i be so grateful if you could help me, i saw other solutions but didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the related `answers` by including it in the views context, so you `QuestionDetailView` becomes

```
class QuestionDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'anwserquestions/question_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'question'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(QuestionDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['answers'] = Answer.objects.filter(post=self.get_object())
        return context
```

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could be of help. Can you please accept the answer as being correct?